# how to assign the email address for every form in a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a website where a user can post anything he wants to sell and others can see it and send a message to him. I am using a while loop in to retrieve the information from the database. My question is I have a contact button for every post and when someone clicks on it, it opens a dialog box where users can fill the message and the form sends it to the seller's email address. I am confused on how to assign that particular seller's email from database to that particular item listing.

Here is my present code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($eleclisting))
{ ?>
<div align="center">
<font size="6" color="4684fd"><? echo $row['title']; ?></font><br>
<? $selleremail=array($row['email']); ?>
<font size="3" color="908282"><? echo addslashes($row['description']); ?></font><br>
<font size="3"><? echo "Price: $".$row['price']; ?></font>

<a id="contactpopup" href="#"><button type="button" name="contactbutton"  
id="contactbutton"  value="">contact</button></a>
<hr>
<?  } ?>
```

Below is the form when someone clicks on the contact button

```
<div id="contact" class="contact" style="width:600px;border:#fff medium solid; top:50%;   
margin-top:-120px; display:none; height:300px; z-index:1001; position:fixed; left:50%;   
margin-left:-250px; background:#ebebeb; overflow:auto;">

<form action="listingcontact.php" method="POST">
Message
<br><textarea name="message" style="min-width:500px; max-width:500px; max-height:200px;   
min-height:200px;"></textarea> <br>
Email <input type="email" name="contactemail" id="contactemail" style="min-width:250px;   
max-width:250px; min-height:25px; max-height:25px;"><br><br><input type="submit"   
value="send">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" id="cancel">close</button> 
</form>
</div>
```

sorry if the code is confusing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply use ajax/jquery to get email address and pass to email function.

Comment: is it not possible to do it in php? I just started learning ajax and I am better at php when compared to ajax as of now. So I am wondering if there is any other option as I am starting to learn ajax now. Thanks!

Comment: When a user submits the form, the contact ID will need to be part of what is being sent. Simplest is to add a hidden field containing the sellers ID to the form.

Comment: There is a way . if your contact form contains email address or that user id. you can pass that in hidden form on form submit and pass it to email function. this would be simple.

Comment: okay I will try it now. Thanks once again guys!

Comment: Do you have something against CSS?

Comment: haha no. I just am trying to figure it out as I am just testing it, so I just included all the style option in the html for now. But I am making a seperate css file for styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add an attribute `data-email` in the contact popup link as below:

```
<a id="contactpopup" class="opencontactpopup" href="#" data-email="<?php echo $row['email'];?>">....</a>
```

Then in your form add a hidden field for holding the email id like:

```
<form action="listingcontact.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="tomail" id="tomail" value="">
//your remaining code
</form>
```

When clicking on the popup link add the corresponding email to the hidden field as below:

```
<script>
$('.opencontactpopup').click(function(){
    var tomail  =   $(this).attr('data-email');
    $('#tomail').val(tomail);
    //your remaining code
})
</script>
```

Now when submitting the form you can get the email id from the field `$_POST['tomail']`. Hope this will help you. But this is not the right way to use the email id as public.